# Creating a dynamic hierarchical numbering in EXCEL. Reset the count after certain criteria is met

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to create a gantt chart sheet with dynamic hierarchical numbering. The set up of the chart is like so:

[The set up and what is currently achieved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYUtI.png)

Formulas used:

**B column** `=D13&"."&E13&"."&F13&"."&G13`

**D column** `=IF(tipas<>"", IF(ROW(ps.nr)=ROW($D$9)+4,1,IF(tipas="R","",IF(tipas="PS",MAX(prev.col.range)+1, MAX(prev.col.range)))),"")`

**E column** `=IF(tipas<>"", IF(OR(tipas="PS", tipas="R"),"",IF(ROW(s.nr)=ROW($E$9)+4,1,IF(tipas="S",MAX(prev.col.range)+1, MAX(prev.col.range)))),-1)`

**F column** `=IF(tipas<>"", IF(OR(tipas="PS",tipas="S",tipas="R"),"",IF(ROW(d.nr)=ROW($F$9)+4,1,IF(OR(tipas="D",tipas="DG",tipas="M"),MAX(prev.col.range)+1, MAX(prev.col.range)))),-1)`

**G Column** currently the same as F

> **Explaining for formulas:**
>
> "Tipas" is a named range reffering to current row H column
>
> "ps.nr", "s.nr", "dg.nr", "d.nr" are named ranges for current row
> number
>
> ["prev.col.range"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFYJt.png) is a named range getting range from header row
> until current row

As far as the chart types ("tipas" Column H) are set up in perfect order PS then S and D then it works kind of perfectly.

The problem starts when I try to achieve the dynamical part. For example if I change type to S anywhere in the middle and there are tasks (type D) before it the counting set's off and the numbering is lost.

[Illustration of what I'm trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bgxjw.png)

The main question would be:

How could I reset the numbering of F column if the value of column H is PS or S and stop the addition to the number if the value is DG?
While column G should start the count only if the value of column H is DG and stop and reset if it's anything else than DG.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this formula in F13:

```
=IF(H13<>"",IF(OR(H13="PS",H13="S",H13="R"),"",IF(ROW(H13)=ROW($F$9)+4,1,IF(G13="",IF(OR(H13="D",H13="DG",H13="M"),MAX(INDIRECT("F"&AGGREGATE(14,6,1/(($H$13:H13="PS")+($H$13:H13="S"))*ROW($H$13:H13),1)&":"&CELL("address",F12)))+1,MAX(INDIRECT("F"&AGGREGATE(14,6,1/(($H$13:H13="PS")+($H$13:H13="S"))*ROW($H$13:H13),1)&":"&CELL("address",F12)))),F12))),-1)
```

This one in G13:

```
=IF(AND(OR(H12="DG",G12<>""),OR(H13="D",H13="M")),IF(H13="R","",IF(G12="",1,G12+1)),"")
```

They should returns you what you were expecting (as far as the data you provided can assure that). Test and send feedback. Questions and/or reports of errors/misfunctions are welcome and will most likely be addressed.

Comment: That works like a charm, Tested with current data input and it seems to be working as intended.